# addEventListener function not working with 'onkeyup' event

Tags: javascript

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = initialise;

use = document.getElementById("use");

function initialise() {
    username = document.getElementById('username');
    username.addEventListener('onkeydown', respond, false);
}

function respond() {
    alert();
    //if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    //    use.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

The `username` variable here is an input text field in another HTML document, looking like this:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
```

This is not working; how can I make it work?

Comment: when using addEventListener you omit the `on` in the event name

Comment: @PatrickEvans Post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using [**addEventListener**](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/element.addEventListener.html) you omit the **"on"** prefix in the event name

```
addEventListener('keydown', , /**/,/**/);
addEventListener('click', , /**/,/**/);
addEventListener('mouseover', , /**/,/**/);
//etc
```

instead of

```
addEventListener('onkeydown', , /**/,/**/);
addEventListener('onclick', , /**/,/**/);
addEventListener('onmouseover', , /**/,/**/);
//etc
```

[Spec for event list types](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/dom3events/raw-file/tip/html/DOM3-Events.html#event-types-list)

However if supporting older IE browsers you will need [attachEvent](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/element.addEventListener.html#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent) which uses **"on"** prefix

Answer (score 2):

Use `keydown` Instead of `Onkeydown`.